# use for loop to concat dataframe to a larger dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

my question is for every step of for loop, a new dataframe will be generated. I want to concat the data frames together to have a larger one but somehow my function will only return the last step of the result rather than the merged result

```
def crossV(clf,data,n):
    cvResult=pd.DataFrame()
    for i in range(n+2)[2:]:
        cvResult=pd.DataFrame()
        tt=array(tuple(x[1:i] for x in data))
        qq=array(tuple(x[0] for x in data))
        recall_rate=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10,scoring='recall')*100
        precision_rate=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10,scoring='precision')*100
        accuracy_rate=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10,scoring='accuracy')*100
        index_i=Series(np.repeat(i-1,10))
        classifier_i=Series(np.repeat(str(clf)[:7],10))
        recall_rate=Series(recall_rate)
        precision_rate=Series(precision_rate)
        accuracy_rate=Series(accuracy_rate)
        rate={"classfier":classifier_i,"model":index_i,"recall":recall_rate,"precision":precision_rate,"accuracy":accuracy_rate}
        result=pd.concat(rate,axis=1)
    cvResult=cvResult.append(result)
    return(cvResult)
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe result = pd.concat( [result, rate], ignore_index=True)  ??

Comment: BTW: add `spaces` around `=` and after `,` to make code more readable - see: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @fasttooth unfortunately it does not work :(

Comment: @furas thank you so much! I am really new to Python will def pay attention to that next time. bad habit in R lol

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the right answer, it is more readable written as answer.

I think the right logic should be ( but I can be very wrong):

```
def crossV(clf,data,n):
    cvResult=pd.DataFrame() #create an empty DF here. 
    for i in range(n+2)[2:]:
        # cvResult=pd.DataFrame() -- remove this line. 
        tt=array(tuple(x[1:i] for x in data))
        qq=array(tuple(x[0] for x in data))
        recall_rate=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10,scoring='recall')*100
        precision_rate=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10,scoring='precision')*100
        accuracy_rate=cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, tt, qq, cv=10,scoring='accuracy')*100
        index_i=Series(np.repeat(i-1,10))
        classifier_i=Series(np.repeat(str(clf)[:7],10))
        recall_rate=Series(recall_rate)
        precision_rate=Series(precision_rate)
        accuracy_rate=Series(accuracy_rate)
        rate={"classfier":classifier_i,"model":index_i,"recall":recall_rate,"precision":precision_rate,"accuracy":accuracy_rate}
        # result=pd.concat(rate,axis=1) --remove this line as well. 
        # I think you don't need the "result" variable. 

        # move this line inside and make a little change:
        #cvResult=cvResult.append(result) 
        cvResult = pd.concat([cvResult, rate], ignore_index=True)
    return(cvResult)
```

Can you please try this and let us know if it works? 
I think one of your problem is the way you use pd.concat(obj) , the obj should be a list of item or a dict of pd.Series.... 
but you didn't concat rate with anything else. 
and the use of variable "result" is unnecessary to me. 
but, again, I could be wrong.

Comment: I agree - `result` is unnecessary. `cvResult` should be used in place of `result`.

Comment: it still did not work the error is "cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object" but thx @fasttooth :)

Comment: oh , you need to do rate = pd.DataFrame( {"classfier":classifier_i,"model":index_i,"recall":recall_rate,"precision":precision_rate,"accuracy":accuracy_rate})  to make it a DataFrame before you concat it.